# pandas select index element by multiple location

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a trivial thing in R but seems quite confusing to me in python pandas. How could I subset "Index" by multiple location.

```
import pandas as pd
unique_index = pd.Index(list('abcdefg'))
#- Not working, I only want 0 and 2.
unique_index[0, 2]
#- or dont want 0, 2; also not working
unique_index[-0, -2]
```

Many thanks.

Comment: pass a list : ``unique_index[[0, 2]]``. You could read the documentation to get more insight into using Pandas

Comment: Also, in python, the negative indexing does not work as in R, as it does something different. You have to be specific in listing your indices, or use numpy to generate them : ``unique_index[np.r_[1, 3 : len(unique_index)]]``

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks! Would you like to exand your comment as answer?

Comment: Oh I think it's fine. I'm glad it helped.